# inner product and measure theory question

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory, fourier-analysis

(S,(f,g)) is an inner product space, and $(v_n)_{n\in{\mathbb N}}$ is an orthonormal set of vectors.

a) Show that, though ($v_n$) is a bounded sequence in norm, there is no subsequence which converges.

b) How do I go about showing that $lim_{n\to{\infty}}$ 1/N $\sum$ $u_n$=0 in the norm?

Do I have to go about using the idea that this type of space is not compact? closed but not bounded? or bounded but not closed?
I am having difficulties, pleas give details.

Comment: Just do some computation. a) What is $\|v_n-v_m\|$ for $n \neq m$? b) What is $\|\sum_n u_n\|$?

Comment: ||$\sum_n{u_n}$||=$\infty$ since for each n ||$u_n$||=1 in a orthonormal space, but doesn't that tell me the limit goes to 1 as n goes to infinity? I don't understand why is 0

Comment: How can the finite sum of vectors possibly have infinite norm??? Compute $\| \sum_{n=1}^N u_n \|^2$ using the inner product.

Comment: I thought n went to infinity, if n$\leq$N, then the norm of the sum is =N, right? I know these are elemntary questions but I do want to learn

Comment: Just compute the norm. It is not N.

Answer (score 1):

Part (a) is straightforward. If $v_n$'s are orthonormal, then $\|v_n\| = 1$ for all $n$. So it is a bounded sequence. For each $n \neq m$, $\| v_n - v_m \|^2 = \langle v_n - v_m, v_n - v_m \rangle = 2$. So it violates Cauchy's criterion for convergence.

The notation in part (b) seems confusing. What is $u_n$, should that be $v_n$? What is the range of the summation, from $1$ to $N$? My guess would be $\lim_{N \to \infty} \frac{\sum_{n=1}^N v_n}{N}$. Then

$$\| \frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=1}^N v_n \|^2 = \langle \frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=1}^N v_n, \frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=1}^N v_n \rangle = \frac{1}{N^2} \sum_{n=1}^N \|v_n\|^2 = \frac{1}{N} \to 0,$$

where the second equality follows from the linearity of inner product and orthogonality of $v_n$'s.